# Url arguments with Django ajax datatable?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, datatable

I have a template, usersummary.html. It shows details about a specific user by relying on a URL parameter. I'd like to display some of the data in a datatable, which would involve an AJAX datatable displaying data based on the same URL parameter.

Using django-datatables-view:

views.py:

```
from django_datatables_view.base_datatable_view import BaseDatatableView

def usersummary(request, id):
    return render(request, 'app/usersummary.html')

class testdatatableJSON(BaseDatatableView):
    model = User
    columns = ['item1', 'item2']
    # This class uses django-datatables-view
    # It returns JSON for the datatable to consume via AJAX
    # I'd like to filter it to display only data relating to the user id defined in the url for template usersummary.html
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.usersummary, name='usersummary'),
url(r'^testdatatable/$', testdatatableJSON.as_view(), name='testdatatable')
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table').DataTable({
    "ajax": "{% url 'testdatatable' %}"
# This controls table in usersummary.html template
```

I'd thought that adding a method to the testdatatableJSON class like below would work, but alas not (presumably because the id parameter isn't actually passed in when consumed via AJAX). If I pass in a hard-coded example to test it, like "id=1", it works fine.

```
def get_initial_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    return User.objects.filter(id=self.kwargs['id'])
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

views.py

```
def usersummary(request, id):
    return render(request,{'user_id':id}, 'app/usersummary.html')
```

template

```
var user_id= {{user_id}}
$('#table').DataTable({
"ajax": {"url":"{% url 'testdatatable' %}",
"data":{"id":user_id}}
# This controls table in usersummary.html template
```

Then add filter_queryset method to the testdatatableJSON class like

```
def filter_queryset(self, qs):
    # use request parameters to filter queryset

    # simple example:
    user_id = self.request.GET.get('id', None)
    if user_id:
        qs = qs.filter(id=user_id)
    return qs
```

hope this will work..